# How to handle a patch request

Tags: rest, api, mongoose, jsx

So my put request looks like this:

```
router.put('/user/:id', function(req, res, next){
  User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body).then(function(){
    User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(function(user){

      res.send(user);

    });
  });
});
```

And I would like to know how to create a patch request primarily to update and array of objects that is formatted in my user model. I only want to send the data I would like to change as opposed to re-sending the whole array each time. This would also cause problems as multiple requests to the api may be sent at once meaning it may update data incorrectly. So what is the patch equivalent of the code above?

Thanks, Ed.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code snippet a couple of times and it seems to me that it already works as a patch request, since you can send whatever data you like and it works well, it does not replace all original data.

Nevertheless, i find your code quite complicated when it could be so much simpler!

You are doing find twice which is very inneficient and completely unnecesary. It's possible to have *findByIdAndUpdate* return the updated user by just adding a simple parameter: *{new: true}*. Also you don't need to use the *{_id: }* notation.

Finally, you are also not returning any errors in case they happen, which is a very bad practice.

Here is the fixed code:

```
router.patch('/user/:_id', (req, res) => {

  User.findByIdAndUpdate( req.params._id , req.body, {

      new: true

    }).then(function(user) {
    res.send(user);

    //in case of error
  }, function(err) {
    res.send(err);
  });
});
```

Notice also how i change router.put for *router.patch*. This is algo a very good practice since this update is NOT replacing the original data like a normal put request, is just altering it with only whatever you are sending, which makes this only a patch request.

Hope this is useful to someone!